# CSS3 overlapping

Tags: css

How can I prevent CSS3 overlapping?   They are all

```
<span> precious </span> <span> and </span> <span> cute </span>
```

And my CSS is

```
span 
{
    margin : 20px;
    min-width: 150px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:white;
    border: 2px solid white;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

The overlapping looks like this

[image]

Thank you, excellent CSS3 experts at Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the property 
`display:inline-block;` 
to prevent the overlapping. The problem is that a `<span>` element by default has the property `display:inline;`. This is great for text but means that the `top` and `bottom` values of `margin` and `padding` can't be set as an inline element should only be as high as the text contained within.

Comment: Thanks a lot old friend